# mysql - is there a tool that can show a live log of all the sql commands the mysql engine receives?

Tags: mysql

using mysql - is there a tool that can show a live log of all the sql commands the mysql engine receives?

a. It would be helpfull to see explain plan for the DML commands.
b. It would be helpfull if it could be turned on and off on a mysql server with no need to restart the service.
c. open source/free like the mysql itself would be nice.
Thanks.

Comment: You mean something like cakePHP's query log?

Comment: Check this question, too: [Is there a tool like Microsoft's “SQL Server Profiler” for MySQL?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9852/is-there-a-tool-like-microsofts-sql-server-profiler-for-mysql/9881#9881)

Answer (score 3):

You first need to activate the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html). There must be some tools around to help you parse this log, my favourite being :

```
tail -f /path/to/mysql.log
```

;)

Unfortunately, this may not be disabled dynamically, you would need to restart the server in order to activate/disable the log.

Careful, though, activating this log has a severe performance impact. Do not use it in production.

Comment: Or the slow query log - with time-limit 0.000 seconds.

Comment: This allows for real time on-off toggling. (change from 0 to 10 seconds and back)

Comment: Much practical solution, indeed. Note that the minimum value for long_query_time is 1 (second) in MySQL <= 5.0.something, if I recall.

Comment: You can edit comments - up to 5 minutes from posting them. (and you can delete them - any time)

Comment: Oh... thanks for the tip. BTW I upped your answer, which I believe fully anwers the OP's need, unlike mine.

Comment: My answer? I haven't answered :)

Comment: Your comment on my answer, I mean... :o)